# Git mergetool generates unwanted .orig files

Tags: git, version-control

When I do a merge conflict resolution with Kdiff3 (and other merge tool I tried) I noticed that on resolution a `*.orig` file is created. Is there a way for it to not create that extra file?

Comment: Finally I googled this damn thing. Thank you for asking this question 

Answer (score 920, accepted):

A possible solution from [`git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

```
git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false
```

> After performing a merge, the original file with conflict markers can be saved as a file with a `.orig` extension.
>   If this variable is set to `false` then this file is not preserved.
>   Defaults to `true` (i.e. keep the backup files).

The alternative being not adding or ignoring those files, as suggested in this [gitguru article](http://web.archive.org/web/20090328164007/http://gitguru.com/2009/02/22/integrating-git-with-a-visual-merge-tool/),

> `git mergetool` saves the merge-conflict version of the file with a “`.orig`” suffix.
>   Make sure to delete it before adding and committing the merge or add `*.orig` to your `.gitignore`.

[Berik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/439096/berik) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251681/git-mergetool-generates-unwanted-orig-files/1251696?noredirect=1#comment80373582_1251696) to use:

```
find . -name \*.orig 
find . -name \*.orig -delete
```

[Charles Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19563/charles-bailey) advises in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251681/diff-tool-generates-unwanted-orig-files/1251871#1251871) to be aware of **internal diff tool settings** which could also generate those backup files, no matter what git settings are.

- kdiff3 has its own settings (see "[Directory merge](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/options.html#id2566994)" in its manual).
- other tools like WinMerge can have their own backup file extension (WinMerge: `.bak`, as mentioned in [its manual](http://winmerge.org/docs/manual/Configuration.html#Configuration_backup)).

So you need to reset those settings as well.

Comment: Editing the settings in kdiff itself worked for me: Settings > Configure Kdiff3 > Directory. Uncheck the box labeled "Backup files (.orig)"

Comment: `git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false`, Solved for P4Merge on Mavericks 10.9.2. Thanks :)

Comment: found a set of `.gitignore` for opendiff generated files [in here](https://github.com/sebreh/SBRXCallbackURLKit/blob/master/.gitignore). may be useful for someone ;)

Comment: @Hlung Interesting. That should be added or referenced in https://github.com/github/gitignore or http://www.gitignore.io/

Comment: just want to note that this works for me using 'meld' as well.

Comment: Note that if you're manually editing your .gitconfig, you want the `keepBackup = false` under `[mergetool]`, not under `[mergetool "BeyondCompare4"]` or whatever visual merge tool you have configured.

Comment: git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false, solved for DiffMerge the problem too! Many thanks! It was so useful

Comment: You may want to use `find . -name \*.orig` to find these files and `find . -name \*.orig -delete` to delete them

Comment: I have been using `git clean -f` to remove unwanted `.orig` files. This may be a simpler move, but is probably an indicator of how little I know about git.

Comment: `rm ./**/*.orig` is a shorter alternative to the find command.

Comment: @BenjaminHammerNørgaard True. But I always prefer to `find` (list files) first, check that what I am about to delete is indeed what I want, *then* delete it. Using `rm` with wildcards (`*` or `**`) is anxiety-inducing for me ;)

Comment: @VonC but if you are in a git repo it's not that hard to undo a mistake. Just don't forget the `.`. Wouldn't be too good to do `rm /**/*.orig`.

Answer (score 95):

You have to be a little careful with using `kdiff3` as while `git mergetool` can be configured to save a `.orig` file during merging, the default behaviour for `kdiff3` is to also save a `.orig` backup file independently of `git mergetool`.

You have to make sure that `mergetool` backup is off:

```
git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false
```

and also that kdiff3's settings are set to not create a backup:

```
Configure/Options => Directory Merge => Backup Files (*.orig)
```

Comment: `Configure/Options => Directory Merge => Backup Files (*.orig)` really helped get rid of all the strange io-slave, klauncher «» unknown protocol, and couldn't create .orig errors. thank you

Comment: Why does `git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false` have to be set?

Comment: let me fix your first line "You have to be a little crazy to use kdiff3" - there :-)

Comment: @TimJarvis I use kdiff3 all the time and I like it. I wonder if there is a reason for calling it "a little crazy to use kdiff3" or if that is just joking (I see the smiley face, I won't be offended either way, I'm earnestly asking)

Comment: @QuinnWilson It was mostly just a joke - there are many better tools than kdiff3 though, if you like it you will probably absolutely love tools like p4Merge etc.

Answer (score 42):

The option to save the .orig file can be disabled by configuring KDiff3

[image: KDiff3 Backup file .orig option]

Comment: This should be the real solution.

Comment: Works for me. Thank you so much @richard-pierre

Comment: I already had the global git config set properly but still had those .orig files on rebase/merge etc. The Kdiff3 settings finally did the trick.

Answer (score 40):

To be clear, the correct git command is:

```
git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false
```

Both of the other answers have typos in the command line that will cause it to fail or not work correctly.

Answer (score 25):

I use this to clean up all files ending in ".orig":

```
function git-clean-orig {
    git status -su | grep -e"\.orig$" | cut -f2 -d" " | xargs rm -r
}
```

If you are a scaredy-cat :) you could leave the last part off just to list them (or leave off the `-r` if you want to approve each delete):

```
function git-show-orig {
    git status -su | grep -e"\.orig$" | cut -f2 -d" "
}
```

Comment: Totally useful if you still want the backups until you get ready to commit.

Comment: You could also add *.orig in .gitignore on the top level if you keep merge backups around.

Answer (score 22):

I simply use the command

```
git clean -n *.orig
```

check to make sure only file I want remove are listed
then

```
git clean -f *.orig
```

Comment: A good tip! It would be good if you also added the other answers regarding gitconfig settings (from other answers).

Answer (score 9):

Besides the correct answers offered as long term solutions, you can use git to remove all unnecessary files once for you with the `git clean -f` command but use `git clean --dry-run` first to ensure nothing unintended would happen.

This has the benefit of using tested built in functionality of Git over scripts specific to your OS/shell to remove the files.

Comment: Yes, but be very careful as this command does a lot more than remove the .orig files.

Answer (score 8):

Or just add

*.orig

to your global gitignore

Comment: Not a huge fan because it still leaves garbage in your local repository.

Answer (score 3):

```
git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false
```

This should work for Beyond Compare (as mergetool) too

Answer (score 2):

If you're working on a Windows machine - you can turn off backups with this command

```
git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false
```

If you don't want to do that, you can easily delete all the `.orig` files using this powershell command

```
ls -Recurse C:\path\to\repository\*.orig | rm
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows:

1. in File `Win/Users/HOME/.gitconfig` set `mergetool.keepTemporaries=false`
2. in File `git/libexec/git-core/git-mergetool`, in the function `cleanup_temp_files()` add `rm -rf -- "$MERGED.orig"` within the else block.

Comment: See the accepted answer. This modifies core tools and is not scalable.