# Avoid orphaned .orig files after resolving conflicts from a Git merge

Tags: git, merge

After I perform a Git merge and resolve the conflicts, there are leftover .orig versions of the conflicting files. How can I automatically delete those after the conflict is successfully resolved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Diff tool generates unwanted .orig files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251681/diff-tool-generates-unwanted-orig-files)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git mergetool generates unwanted .orig files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251681/git-mergetool-generates-unwanted-orig-files)

Answer (score 53):

It's the git mergetool that produces these files, you can disable them with this command:

```
git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false
```

See the git-config manpage:

http://man.he.net/man1/git-config

Comment: I've got response: $ git config global mergetool.keepBackup false
error: key does not contain a section: global

Comment: Sorry for the late response but i'm putting it here for any future visitors. You forgot to add - infront of global when you called git config. -global is a flag that tells git to operate on the global (per machine) configuration instead of the local per repository one.

Comment: Watch out for the dash infront of -global -- because of the formatting that dash is not compatible with the command line.  Use  this `git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false`

Comment: The orig files may also be created by the external merge tool (kdiff3).  See this Q/A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251681/diff-tool-generates-unwanted-orig-files

Answer (score 5):

Quite likely those files are created by KDiff3 tool you probably using for merging files. The easiest way to solve the problem is where it was originated:

1. open **KDiff3**,
2. go to **Settings / Configure KDiff3 / Directory**,
3. un-tick checkbox "**Backup files (.orig)**"

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
git status -su | grep -e"\.orig$" | cut -f2 -d" " | xargs rm
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10744524/670915 for details

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't create *.orig files. It only marks the sections in the conflicting file with `<<<< ... ==== ... >>>>`.

Which tool are you using? You'll have to disable it there.

But tools like WinMerge indeed create these files, but they automatically process and remove them when you mark the file as resolved within the editor.

Answer (score -1):

Even I was geting the same error, when I copy + paste the command from a word document. But I tried removing the `--` before the switch `global` and re-type it manually on the command prompt. It WORKED!

May be it was due to some mis-interpretation of the Charectes in the MS_Wrod and the Command Prompt.