# How to delete .orig files after merge from git repository?

Tags: git

Some how .orig files are checked in my git repository during merge, which are now displayed in modified and un-tracked sector. But I don't want this files anymore in my repository. How to do that.

```
    modified:   Gemfile.lock.orig
    #   modified:   Gemfile.orig
    #   modified:   app/assets/images/bg_required.png.orig
    #   modified:   app/assets/javascripts/application.js.orig
    
    etc...
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/removing-untracked-files-from-your-git-working-copy

Comment: @ziu, I want to remove files that are already present in my repository, checked in by git merge or by some other developer

Comment: I missed the part about checked-in files. However, the .orig files are written by mergetool. It sounds to me as a non-clean conflict resolution.

Comment: Do you need to completely remove the file from the whole history?

Comment: check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history

Answer (score 320, accepted):

Best solution in this case is to keep it simple and get rid of those files independently of git:

```
cd /your/repo/directory
find . -name '*.orig' -delete
```

Alternatively, in Windows/PowerShell, you can run the following command

```
cd \your\repo\directory
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter '*.orig' | Remove-Item
```

Comment: If you get an predicate error use: find . -name '*.orig' | xargs rm -f

Comment: Just as a warning, using 'find -delete' can be dangerous. Please check that the directory (in this case '.') is correct to make sure that you are only deleting what you want to delete

Comment: What about Windows?

Comment: @Panzercrisis if you are using Windows you will probably already have a terminal emulator via which you interface with Git. I would recommend "gitforwindows" which contains BASH with all other commonly needed tools.

Comment: Don't accidentally run `find . '*.orig' -delete`... it deletes your whole repository; ask me how I know

Comment: I google for and come back to this answer at least once a month, whenever I've just done a big messy merge and have a bunch of .orig's laying about.

Answer (score 163):

Try `git clean` more info you can find [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html) or [here](http://travisjeffery.com/b/2011/12/keeping-your-git-repo-clean-of-orig-files/)

Comment: I can clean untracked files, but what about removing such files that are already in the repository.

Comment: you have to first remove file from repository `git rm <filename>` and then commit.after this add *.orig file into git ignore.

Comment: Thanks @Amar, its working, but problem now is that git shows these files are deleted and I don't want to commit this.

Comment: I think this is a better solution than the one marked as answer.

Comment: `git clean -i` is really nice. it will give you a list of files that will be deleted and give you options on how to deal with the list (filter the list, being able to delete everything on the list, and some other options).

Comment: You can use git clean with patterns to help delete only files the *.orig files:   
`git clean -f -e '*.*' -e '!*.orig'`   
   
There is only an exclude pattern, but it has a little support for negative patterns.  So we can exclude all files `*.*`, and then negate the exclusion of just the `*.orig` files.

Comment: @PPPaul That's a great tip, thanks! … one thing it didn't do was to consider removing a modified ".orig" file that I had. I needed to get rid of that one a different way. Is there some other flag I can add that will do this?

Comment: clean was created for this, but it also removes all the untracked files (including the ones you just created but didn't add yet). This just cost me an hour's worth of new files :/ but this might be because my usage pattern (doing my changes in an IDE and then calling: `git add . && git commit`) is non-standard.

Comment: you need git clean -f

Comment: In my case, I needed the -x flag, for including ignored files, when running the `git clean` command.

Answer (score 132):

you can do:

```
git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false
```

For more info, refer to to [Git mergetool generates unwanted .orig files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251681/git-mergetool-generates-unwanted-orig-files)

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately `git clean` doesn't work for me because I have `*.orig` added to my global gitignore file, so they're ignored from clean as well. Even running `git clean -x` is no good because I don't want *all* of my ignored files getting deleted. `git clean -i` is helpful, but really I don't want to have to review each and every file.

However, we can use an exclude pattern and negate the match. Preview with this command:

```
git clean -e '!*.orig' --dry-run
```

Then when you're confident, pass the `force` flag to really delete them:

```
git clean -e '!*.orig' -f
```

Based on [leorleor's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/44811993?noredirect=1)

Comment: For me, the negative pattern does not work, it will include all untracked files.

Answer (score 8):

You can ignore files using .gitignore

Just put *.orig in the list like shown here

https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

for deleting current files you can create shell script and run from project folder like below

```
for file in `find *.orig -type f -print`
do
   echo "Deleting file $file"
   git rm $file -f       
done
```

Comment: Though he certainly can do this, it's not the right thing to do here :)

Comment: I thinks it's a good idea as it keeps the backup but doesn't interfere staged files

Comment: @akazemis - you'd think so, but when you are grepping for code you see twice as many search results as you want (which gives you a false perception of what is in your latest code). It's so rare that I'd rather just live with the danger of not having orig files. It's better just to commit regularly.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat You can ignore those files during grepping

Answer (score 3):

`git rm Gemfile.lock.orig`
and the rest of the files you don't need.
`git commit --amend`

To completely remove those blobs,
`git gc --prune=0 --aggressive`

Comment: @linquizebut commit of git rm Gemfile.lock.orig will go in last commit using amend, right? is there any other way to not to have any commit for such file?

Answer (score 2):

For me `git clean -f` removed all *.oig files. And keeps the ones that were already there before.

This is what it (almost) looked like after the merge:

```
$ git status
On branch feature/xyz
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature/xyz' by 568 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .idea/codeStyles/
    .idea/misc.xml.orig
```

`.idea/codeStyles/` was already there before the merge as an untracked file. `.idea/misc.xml.orig` (and a lot more) had to be removed.

=> Using `git clean -f`:

```
$ git clean -f
Removing .idea/misc.xml.orig
```

resulted in:

```
$ git status
On branch feature/xyz
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature/xyz' by 568 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .idea/codeStyles/
```

Comment: Make sure you've added files using git add <file> that you need before running this command. I accidentally ran this command and it removed all the files (which I wanted) that were not added to git

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do `git status -s | grep "\.orig$" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n1 -r echo rm`

TL;DR;

`git status -s` allows you to get all modified/missing files in respect of the index

`grep "\.orig$"` filter out files, keeping the ending by ".orig"

`awk '{print $2}'` lists file name (skipping git information e.g. A, M, ??)

`xargs -n1 -r echo rm` prints remove commands on every arguments (-n1: one at a time and -r: skip when empty) just copy&paste the commands double-checking for files to remove.

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you on a **windows machine**, you can execute this command in PowerShell.

```
ls -r *.orig | rm -f
```

Or if you prefer verbose PowerShell

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.orig | Remove-Item -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

You can automate this process with pre-commit hook. To do so, just go inside you project folder, and search for hidden folder `.git`.
Inside it you will find `hooks` directory, open it and cr8 a file named `pre-commit` with the next contains:

```
echo "Looking for .orig files to remove"
pwd=$(pwd)
find . -name '*.orig' -delete 
echo "Done removing .orig files"
```

Now it will cleanup orig files always before you committed something, so no necessary to keep it in gitignore.

Answer (score -4):

`git rm <file>`

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm

Also add files/directories you want to ignore to your .gitignore file.

Comment: `git rm <file> <file>` Just list them.

Comment: Then you need to list all the files, or use a tool like find to pass them to git rm, or use a shell glob and loop over them. Git does not duplicate this standard Unix command-line functionality.

Comment: orig files are not added to the repository, so there's no need to use `git rm`, just use `rm` instead