# Invalid css error when deploying to heroku and assets precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I try to deploy my app to heroku but i'm getting this error:

```
Invalid CSS after "  height: 4em;": expected "}", was "<<<<<<< HEAD"
```

Is the `HEAD` a problem in this situation?

I validated my `custom.css` file in w3 but nothing is changed.

Full trace of the error like that:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
          Running: rake assets:precompile
          DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/Rakefile:7)
          DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/Rakefile:7)
          rake aborted!
          Invalid CSS after "  height: 4em;": expected "}", was "<<<<<<< HEAD"
          (in /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.orig)
          (sass):1166
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1147:in `expected'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1083:in `expected'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1078:in `tok!'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:535:in `block'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:528:in `ruleset'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:552:in `block_child'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:545:in `block_contents'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:82:in `stylesheet'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:27:in `parse'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/engine.rb:342:in `_to_tree'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass/rails/compressor.rb:12:in `compress'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:74:in `compress'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:243:in `block in css_compressor='
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `call'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `evaluate'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:193:in `block in evaluate'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `each'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `evaluate'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:26:in `initialize'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `new'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `build_asset'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:19:in `block in compile'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:219:in `block in each_logical_path'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:206:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each_entry'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:204:in `block in each_file'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each_file'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:217:in `each_logical_path'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
          /tmp/build_cb755c6e-cfb5-4008-83be-23c2f4adbe3a/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
          Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
          (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    !
    !     Precompiling assets failed.
    !

    !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have a [git merge](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merge-Conflicts) conflict in your css file. Resolve the conflict, commit the changes, and try pushing again. **Update:** Just noticed that it is a *.orig file. Git mergetool will save a backup of the the file with the markers (like <<<<<<< HEAD etc) and append the suffix '.orig'. You should delete these before committing or if you want to keep them around for other reasons you should add *.orig to your .gitignore. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251681/diff-tool-generates-unwanted-orig-files) for more information on strategies for handling mergetool backups.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error in parsing the CSS file called "custom.css.orig". The .orig suffix and the "<<<<<<< HEAD" part of the error message makes me think that you have committed a merge conflict diff file by mistake. You probably didn't mean to commit that file, and if you remove it you should no longer get this error.