# Move running merge of git to beyond compare

Tags: git, git-merge, beyondcompare3

I made certain changes in my local branch. I didn't commit. I just indexed all changes and moved them to stash.
Now I did a

```
git pull
```

After git pull I did

```
git stash apply
```

Now there are some conflicts. In eclipse I am able to see the conflicts in normal git format

```
<<<< Updated Upstream
ksldjflsdk
sdlkfjdslk
sdlkfjsdlk
===========
sdlkfjdslk
dslkfjdslkfj
dsklfjsdlkjf
>>>>> Stashed Changes
```

Now there are some files with hell lot of conflicts. It is very difficult for me to look up and down and merge. Is there a way I can move current merge process to beyond compare.

I am on git version 1.8.3 and Beyond Compare 3.2.3

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're okay with launching Beyond Compare from the command line, and that you're on Windows. You can add the following lines to your global `.gitconfig` file:

```
[merge]
    tool = bc3
[diff]
    tool = bc3
[difftool "bc3"]
    cmd = "\"c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\""
[mergetool "bc3"]
    cmd = "\"c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\""
```

Edit: Adding Mac commands [straight from site](https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs_osx):

```
git config --global diff.tool bc3
git config --global merge.tool bc3
git config --global mergetool.bc3.trustExitCode true
```

Then you can simply start conflict resolution with the following commands:

```
git mergetool # Starts Beyond Compare for all conflicted files, one at a time.
git mergetool -- <file> # Starts B.C. just for the specified file.
```

Comment: Yup it worked :) thanks a lot.
Can you please quickly explain mein what is git LOCAL, BASE and REMOTE files in my scenario?

Comment: `BASE` is the common ancestor of `LOCAL` and `REMOTE`. The files that `LOCAL` and `REMOTE` represent changes depending on the git operation. If you're merging, `LOCAL` represents the changes you're merging in from a branch, and `REMOTE` represents the file you're merging ***into***. If you're rebasing, it's reversed, `LOCAL` represents the file being merged into, while `REMOTE` represents the file you're merging in. In the case of `git stash apply`, I'm not sure if it's considered to be like a merge or like a rebase.

Comment: I am not rebasing. I'll do simple merge and push.

Answer (score 3):

just an update based on the previous answer whose user seems to be inactive - please upvote the other post - for Beyond Compare 4 that would be (the only difference is the default directory with 4 instead of 3 in it and bcomp.exe turning into bcompare.exe) [Edit: global .gitconfig on Windows machines is usually in user's home directory, i.e. ~ in Git Bash or something like C:\Users\YourUserName]

```
[merge]
    tool = bcompare
[diff]
    tool = bcompare
[difftool "bcompare"]
    cmd = "\"c:/program files/beyond compare 4/bcompare.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\""
[mergetool "bcompare"]
    cmd = "\"c:/program files/beyond compare 4/bcompare.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\""
```

Also git mergetool seems to generate backup files with the .orig ending - BC does not have to do something with it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251681/git-mergetool-generates-unwanted-orig-files) there is a suggestion to just delete these files afterwards and leave the global git settings alone (syntax is for Git Bash):

```
find . -name *.orig -delete
```