# finish git rebase operation after conflict

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

For my job I need to do a git rebase of my feature branch onto the development branch.

These are my commands thus far to prepare the rebase:

```
git checkout feature-branch
git rebase development
# resolve conflicts in Visual Studio
git rebase --continue
```

After this, I'm getting the following in the cmd:

[image: git rebase stuck in shell after conflict]

Now it's just as if I'm typing a novel in Notepad. Hitting enter, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, ... doesn't do anything.

I've already read other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447429/unable-to-finish-a-git-rebase) but this doesn't offer me a clue of how to complete the rebase / exit the shell.

So how do I finish this rebase operation? What buttons do I need to press?

Comment: try `esc`, then  `i`, type your commit message, then when done `esc`, `:wq` then enter

Comment: (this looks like you're using the `vi` editor, if you're familiar with that)

Comment: Thanks. It seems that this gets me back to the "merge conflict" state which I resolved earlier on. Visual Studio git indicates "Detached at xxxxxx"

Comment: Ah after resolving once more, and running `git rebase --continue`, exiting with the keycodes you provided, I'm again on my branch. Then I had to pull the remote commits that weren't mine, and finally I could push my feature branch. I do have some notions of vim, but never used it myself, always bash. But I would never have come up with these keycodes. Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: (Wondering if there's a `nano` equivalent too, I'm more used to that )

Comment: I think this will work: `git config --global core.editor "nano"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've been dropped into the `vim` editor, and currently in *replace* mode.  You can get out of that by just hitting `esc`. Then you can type `i` to enter *insert* mode (which will probably behave more as you'd expect). Type your commit message, then hit `esc` again (back to *command* mode), then `:wq` (write-quit) and enter, and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough rep to post a comment, but as a side note it's possible to configure Git to use a different editor, for example
`git config --global core.editor "code --wait"` would change the default to be `VS Code`

more information on this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36644561/18039381