# How do I clear the unused conflict files down after resolving conflict?

Tags: git, p4merge

I have resolved a conflict using p4Merge. It worked and the file now has the updated text. However in the folder is a load of junk like...

- --> file.txt.BACKUP
- --> file.txt.BASE
- --> file.txt.LOCAL

How do I made sure my merge tool cleans up these files afterwards?

Comment: You can use `git clean -f` to remove all untracked files.  If the merge backups are your only untracked files, that should do the trick.

Comment: why don't you make an answer and I can mark it correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Diff tool generates unwanted .orig files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251681/diff-tool-generates-unwanted-orig-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[git clean](http://csurs.csr.uky.edu/cgi-bin/man/man2html?1+git-clean) should do the trick.

```
git clean -f
```

That will remove to remove **all** untracked files in your repository, so be wary of inadvertently deleting other files. If the merge backups are your only untracked files, go to town. :)